# Replace Empty Indexes of Ansible List with String

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a list called 'inf_list_tmp' in my ansible playbook and it looks like:

```
{
"changed": false,
"ansible_facts": {
    "inf_list_tmp": [
        [],
        [],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-7] - 02/23/2021 07:23:30 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables"
        ],
        [],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-5] - 02/23/2021 07:23:33 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables"
        ],
        [],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-8] - 02/23/2021 07:40:49 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables"
        ],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-1] - 02/23/2021 07:41:21 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables "
        ]
    ]
},
"_ansible_no_log": false
```

}

Now I want to replace empty indexes in above list with a string 'STARTED JOB'

**Expected Output:**

```
"inf_list_tmp": [
        [STARTED JOB],
        [STARTED JOB],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-7] - 02/23/2021 07:23:30 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables"
        ],
        [STARTED JOB],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-5] - 02/23/2021 07:23:33 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables"
        ],
        [STARTED JOB],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-8] - 02/23/2021 07:40:49 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables"
        ],
        [
            "[dataLoaderJobTaskExecutor-1] - 02/23/2021 07:41:21 ES30CLIENT21  [EventHelperServiceImpl] INFO: Sending event notification [STARTED JOB] for tenant [ES30CLIENT21] with variables "
        ]
    ]
```

Below is my code, but it's not giving me expected output:

```
- set_fact: my_list="{{ item.replace(item, 'STARTED JOB') if item|length == 0 else item }}"
  with_items: "{{ inf_list_tmp }}"
```

Is there a way to achieve this within the Ansible playbook? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify the data, e.g.

```yaml
inf_list_tmp: [[], [], [a], [], [b], [], [c], [d]]
```

Q: **"*Replace empty indexes in the above list with a string 'STARTED JOB'*"**

A: The task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        inf_list: "{{ inf_list|default([]) + [_item] }}"
      loop: "{{ inf_list_tmp }}"
      vars:
        _item: "{{ (item|length > 0)|ternary(item,  'STARTED JOB') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  inf_list:
  - STARTED JOB
  - STARTED JOB
  - - a
  - STARTED JOB
  - - b
  - STARTED JOB
  - - c
  - - d
```